# kubernetes(GKE) nginx service(with type loadbalancer) vs ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to decide which would be good for my cluster. An nginx service(which routes requests to their corresponding services) or an ingress(which encapsulates other services) for load-balancing. What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx with kubernetes ingress feature, which is available from v1.1+. 
It accepts a configMap where you can pass all your nginx related custom configuration.

When you use `type: LoadBalancer` in the config, a load balancer (with external ip in case GCE) will be created.

For more info checkout their official repo https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx